# NFS writes to md-raid extremely slow with busy jbd2

Tags: debian, io

As far as I can remember, this problem appeared after upgrade from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy. The symptom is *extremely* slow write performance on the server's dmraid exclusively if written via nfs shares from any client. The performance issue seems to occur after some minutes of transfer and maybe only with large files.

The harddisk's noise in this condition is really concise - as I am talking about my home server, I can tell you by acoustics whether the system is in the problematic state currently :D This may give a hint on the cause as it sounds like seek or random read/write benchmarks, but not like a read benchmark or a write benchmark when done separately.

The problem occurs when using nfs shares on an Ubuntu 14.04 system or/and when using nfs shares on an Mythbuntu 12.04 system - there is no difference in behaviour. For this I had to switch the Mythbuntu system to sftp, because this system copies tv recordings automatically to the server.

Just to underline: copying the very same files via ssh/scp/sftp makes no problem at all and gives good performance! (1 GBit/s network)

Back to a problematic transfer: there the transmitting speed forms waves: it is really slow at ~150-250 KiB/s for approx. 4 seconds, then "sucks" a chunk at ~4-7 MiB/s for approx. 1-2 seconds.

This underlines that there is no network problem, no protocol mistalk, no auxiliary load that may cause the systems to slow down.

Those are the versions:

```
nsk@server7even3:~$ lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)
Release:    7.6
Codename:   wheezy
nsk@server7even3:~$ uname -a
Linux server7even3 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

nfs-kernel-server is at version 1:1.2.6-4

This is an example output of iotop:
well ... I did not managed to copy the output as it is refreshing all the time which clears my selection, but the relevant line looks like:

```
8417 be/3 root     0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.95 % [jbd2/dm-0-8]
```

It does not stick to 99.xx % - this varies between 91.xx-99.99 %

Of course the raid is *not* resyncing just now:

```
nsk@server7even3:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md127 : active raid5 sdf1[0] sdd1[4] sda1[2] sdb1[1]
      11720655360 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
```

Here you can see that it is a raid5 and the filesystem is ext4.

I found some similar issues over the web; but when reading carefully, none of them really matches.

Any advices?

---

**//Edit:**

Disks data:

- Bought: March 2014
- Power on hours: ~6150

Array:

- Created with mdadm with no additional parameters (as far as my notes tell me)
- RAID stride:              128
- RAID stripe width:        384

Partition:

- Aligned to sector:        2048
- Block size:               4096
- Inode size:            256
- Inodes per group:         4096
- Inode blocks per group:   256

This is the second partition on the array

I forgot to tell that the partition additionally is crypted - sorry for that!

```
nsk@server7even3:~$ sudo cryptsetup status /dev/mapper/udisks-luks-uuid-18cea73e-4176-4d8a-b80d-cc5e933beb77-uid0
/dev/mapper/udisks-luks-uuid-18cea73e-4176-4d8a-b80d-cc5e933beb77-uid0 is active and is in use.
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
  keysize: 256 bits
  device:  /dev/md127p2
  offset:  3072 sectors
  size:    15032381407 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

Comment: How old are your disks? Sector size / alignment? Hardware RAID controller (you mention dmraid)?

Comment: I will update my question with the informations